# datagrid view in outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Good afternoon,

I want to make a an outlook looklike datagrid for an addin in Microsoft Outlook.

[image: an outlook looklike datagrid]

i have a code like this:

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("HasAttachments")
dt.Columns.Add("From")
dt.Columns.Add("Subject")
dt.Columns.Add("PartOfBody")
dt.Columns.Add("ReceivedTime")
dt.Columns.Add("Msg_Full_File_Path")
dt.Columns.Add(" ")





For int_Counter As Integer = 0 To str_All_Messages.Length - 1
    Dim file As New FileInfo(str_All_Messages(int_Counter))
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = file.FullName
    dr(1) = file.Extension
    dr(2) = file.Name
    dr(3) = file.Attributes
    dr(4) = file.CreationTime
    dr(5) = file.DirectoryName
    dr(6) = "test"




    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
     
Next

'Next
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
```

Is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: Is it possible, yes. But you really need to update your question with a clear and concise explanation part of this exactly you’re struggling with.  A bunch of code with and end goal is not a question many can or will help with

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Data.DataTable` and `DataGridView` are pure .net based classes not related to the Outlook object model. There is no direct conversion between them.

If you need to build the message body based on the information in any .net class  you must create a convertor which can translate the information into an HTML markup which Outlook understands. The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property from the Outlook object model returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.